# unable to use datamodel with arraylist

Tags: java, jsf

my arraylist is :

```
private static final ArrayList<Order> orderList = 
        new ArrayList<Order>(Arrays.asList(

        new Order("A0001", "Intel CPU", 
                new BigDecimal("700.00"), 1),
        new Order("A0002", "Harddisk 10TB", 
                new BigDecimal("500.00"), 2),
        new Order("A0003", "Dell Laptop", 
                new BigDecimal("11600.00"), 8),
        new Order("A0004", "Samsung LCD", 
                new BigDecimal("5200.00"), 3),
        new Order("A0005", "A4Tech Mouse", 
                new BigDecimal("100.00"), 10)
    ));

private final DataModel<Order> ordering = new ArrayDataModel<Order>(orderList);// this line shows error
    public DataModel<Order> getOrderListDataModel() {

        return ordering;

    }
```

JSF `dataTable` does not contain any method to display the currently selected row numbers. However, I can hack it with `javax.faces.model.DataModel` class, which has a `getRowIndex()` method to return the currently selected row number.

This arraylist actually appears in a tabular form which I am doing through JSF.

I am able to use it with Array of my own type, but not with an arraylist?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

It takes an array, not a list as a parameter.  There is no constructor for a list.  That is, if we are talking about `javax.faces.model.ArrayDataModel`

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

As [the the Javadoc for ArrayDataModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/ArrayDataModel.html) shows, it doesn't have a constructor that takes a `List` as an  argument. It takes an array:

> ArrayDataModel(E[] array)
>   Construct a new ArrayDataModel wrapping the specified array.

Use [ListDataModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/ListDataModel.html) instead

```
private final DataModel<Order> ordering = 
    new ListDataModel<Order>(orderList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are talking about javax/faces/DataModel
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html

If you want to List as data model try using ListDataModel
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/model/ListDataModel.html

In your code try changes as follows,

```
  private static final List<Order> orderList = 
        new ArrayList<Order>(Arrays.asList(

        new Order("A0001", "Intel CPU", 
                new BigDecimal("700.00"), 1),
        new Order("A0002", "Harddisk 10TB", 
                new BigDecimal("500.00"), 2),
        new Order("A0003", "Dell Laptop", 
                new BigDecimal("11600.00"), 8),
        new Order("A0004", "Samsung LCD", 
                new BigDecimal("5200.00"), 3),
        new Order("A0005", "A4Tech Mouse", 
                new BigDecimal("100.00"), 10)
    ));

private final DataModel<Order> ordering = new ListDataModel<Order>(orderList);// this line shows error
    public DataModel<Order> getOrderListDataModel() {

        return ordering;

    }
```

Hope this helps.